# Generic getter method in a class in java

Tags: java, enums

Hey I have defined a class prop as

`

```
class prop{
   String name;
   String address;
   String city;
   public void String getValue(String str){
       String res=null;
       if(str.equals("name"))
         res="john";
       if(str.equals("city"))
          res="london";
       return res;
}`
```

I have defined getter class like this, Is it possible to define general getter method in some other way.

Someone told me use enum class, but I didn't understand how enum will be useful here.

parameter in function getValue(String str) is a String, as it is being called by other class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like so:

```
class Prop{
   public enum Properties {
       Name,
       Address,
       City
   }

   Map<Properties, String> propertyMap;

   public Prop() {
       this.propertyMap = new HashMap<Properties, String>();
   }


   public void String setValue(Properties prop, String value){
      this.propertyMap.put(prop, value);
   }

   public void String getValue(Properties prop){          
           return this.propertyMap(prop);
   }
}
```

To add value:

```
Prop prop = new Prop();
...
prop.setValue(prop.Properties.Name, "Bob");
...
String name = prop.getValue(prop.Properties.Name); //Should be Bob, assuming it did not change.
```

EDIT:
As per your query, you could do something like so:

```
class Prop{
   Map<String, String> propertyMap;

   public Prop() {
       this.propertyMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
   }


   public void String setValue(String prop, String value){
      this.propertyMap.put(prop, value);
   }

   public void String getValue(String prop){
      return this.propertyMap(prop);      
   }
}
```

The *problem* with this approach is that whoever is calling your code has to *guess* or somewhat have some sort of prior knowledge to calling your code. With the enumerations, you are providing, up front, what properties can your map have.

Comment: Isn't there any way to pass parameter String in getValue() function ??

Comment: @user3697669: I have updated my answer. If you are going this path, I would still suggest you stick to enums though.

Answer (score 0):

```
class prop {
    public enum Field {
        NAME, ADDRESS, CITY
    }

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String city;

    public String getValue(Field field) {
       switch(field) {
           case NAME : return name;
           case ADDRESS : return address;
           case CITY : return city;  
       }

       return null;
    }
}
```

Or something.

Bit of a strange way of doing things...

Comment: parameter in function getValue is a String, as it is being called by other class.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed off topic, and I would never use enums in this case, but you can store values in enums:

```
enum Properties {
  Name("John"),
  Address("221B Baker Street"),
  City("London");

  private String value;

  Properties(String value0){
    value = value0;
  }
}
```